# How to scan a QR code from android WebView using JavascriptInterface

Tags: javascript, android, webview, interface, qr-code

I am trying to make an app using a webview as a wrapper for it - almost the whole app lives in this webview (programmed in Javascript). In some point I want to open the mobile camera, scan a QR code and get the actual text from it.

What I have done so far:
I created the WebView activity 
I imported android.webkit.JavascriptInterface in my project, in order to be able to establish a communication between WebView and android system
I created a Java function (scan()) where I open the camera with an new Intent.
I created a Javascript function to call scan() using JavasciptIntereface.

All of these are working as they should – now I have to send back to WebView the image of Qrcode (or the actual text from it) and I don’t know how to proceed.